# Repeated "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle......." error even after readding the Ojdbc.jar file

Tags: eclipse, jdbc

I am very new to Java programming. I use eclipse IDE. I found the "No suitable driver found" error and I fixed it by adding the ojdbc.jar file. And when i run the program, it works just fine. And the moment i run the program again, the same driver not found error occurs again. Seeking help..

Comment: "*No suitable driver*" usually means your JDBC URL is wrong.

Comment: Well, apparently your URL is not "fine" - please post it and the code you use to establish the connection.

Comment: You would also need the ojdbc.jar in your deplyment assembly. Try doing that.

Comment: The problem was fixed after i added the javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar and taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1 file. Thank you a_horse_with_no_name and darshan